# Static libraries and headers in another directories with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, header-files, include-path

I was looking [here](http://segfault.in/2008/04/how-to-create-static-libraries-with-gcc/) how to do static libraries using GCC, and the explanation is pretty clear (despise the fact I had to rewrite the factorial function): I have a function (fact.c), the header of the function (fact.h), and the main function (main.c), all of them in my home directory.

**fact.h**

```
int fact (int);
```

**fact.c**

```
int
fact (int f) {
  if ( f == 0 )
    return 1;
else
    return (f * fact ( f - 1 ));
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fact.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("%d\n", fact(3));
        return 0;
}
```

So I had first to generate the object file (phase 1)...

```
$ gcc -c fact.c -o fact.o
```

...then to generate the static library (phase 2)...

```
$ ar rcs libfact.a fact.o
```

...later to do the static library linking process (phase 3)...

```
$ gcc -static main.c -L. -lfact -o fact
```

...and finally run the program (phase 4 and final)

```
$ ./fact
```

My question is the following. Let's suppose my program will be so big that I had no alternative than put the headers in a header directory (/include/fact.h) and the static libraries will also be in another directory (/lib/libfact.a). In that case, how the compilation and/or the code of this program will change?

**Edit/Problem Solved**: First, the main.c was corrected in order to include a header in another directory called include. Remember that, in this case, both of the .c files are in the main directory.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "include/fact.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("%d\n", fact(3));
        return 0;
}
```

Second, to generate the static library in another directory (phase 2), this is what I had done:

```
$ ar rcs lib/libfact.a fact.o
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your answer,

$ gcc -static main.c -L. -lfact -o fact

-L Add directory to the list of directories to be searched for -l

Its in the link that you gave. If you put the seach direction correctly and low search range, it will not be a problem. Otherwise it is not going to compile the code. Because code did not know where is the header.

Comment: I tried it with the header in the header directory (/include/fact.h) but it gave me an error in the main program that says the file fact.h doesn't exists. Maybe it's not a problem with the compilation only, maybe I have to change something in the include in the main program.

Comment: Please check the directory that you can wrote it wrong. c:// or c:/ or C:// variations maybe have problem. And try to give the exact location of header other than search range.

#include "fact.h" this means that its near the main program. You should use #include <fact.h> try with this.

Comment: I tried, but the problem persists: Error in the main program indicating that the file fact.h doesn't exists.

Comment: I solved the problem. The command you ṕosted, who was also on the link, worked. The problem wasn't in the compilation, was in the code. As a matter of fact, I corrected the include with `#include "include/fact.h"`. Anyway, thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

You can add -I to specify include path(s).

```
gcc -I/include fact.c

gcc -I/include -static main.c -L/lib -lfact -o fact_main
```

Comment: Same problem as above: Error in the main program indicating that the file fact.h doesn't exists.